# How to let your list take the next character after 25 letters?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
lijst = ["h","e","l","l","o","h","o","w","a","r","e","y","o","u"]
aa=['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e']

alfascii = ['097','98','99','100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','109','110','111','112','113','114','115','116','117','118','119','120','121','122']

for c in lijst:
    i = i+1
    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace(alfascii[0],aa[((i))*25%650])
```

I want that the 1st-25th letter of the list(alfascii) are replaced by an 'a', the 26th-50th by a 'j' , the 51th-75th by a 'd'...

Is there a better way to do that then just repeat each letter 25 times in my list(aa)?

Comment: I do not understand your problem. Could you produce a simplified example with explicit inputs and expected outputs? A [mcve]/

Comment: No, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51493768/edit) your question to include the [mcve]

Comment: FYI, `>` is not needed in the question editor for proper indentation, just put spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is if you have to literally type every letter 25 times, than no. Ignored 'lijst' as I don't think it is relevant for your question.

You could simply do:

```
letters = ['a', 'j', 'd']  #The letters you want here
aa = []
for l in letters:
    aa += [l]*25

alfascii = ['097','98','99','100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','109','110','111','112','113','114','115','116','117','118','119','120','121','122']
alfascii = aa[:len(alfascii)]
```

Or if you don't want the helper aa list:

```
letters = ['a', 'j', 'd']  #The letters you want here
alfascii = ['097','98','99','100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','109','110','111','112','113','114','115','116','117','118','119','120','121','122']

for i, l in enumerate(alfascii):
    letter_index = round((i+1)/25 - 0.5)
    alfascii[i] = letters[letter_index]
```